# Why is the CSS not working in this JS toggle? Beginner question

Tags: javascript, css, toggle

I've created a toggle pricing table using code from codpen.io (the original can be found here --> https://codepen.io/kijanmaharjan/pen/dMmdej and copied below). It works on the default setting (ie. toggle off), but when I toggle the switch all the CSS settings are lost. What am I missing?

My site is the-oop-test.xyz and you can test the problem there. I've copy & pasted the code exactly and JS is in the footer.

Thanks for any help, I'm sure the solution is very simple but I can't find it!

**HTML**

```
<section class="pricing-columns pricing-section">
  <label class="toggler toggler--is-active" id="filt-monthly">Monthly</label>
  <div class="toggle">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switcher" class="check">
    <b class="b switch"></b>
  </div>
  <label class="toggler" id="filt-hourly">Hourly</label>
  <div id="monthly" class="wrapper-full">
    <p class="bandwidth">Pricing in USD. Excludes any applicable tax.</p>
    <div id="pricing-chart-wrap">
      <div id="pricing-chart">
        <div id="smaller-plans">
            <div class="plan">
              <div class="price">
                <span class="dollar">$</span>
                <span class="amount" data-dollar-amount="22.59">22.59</span>
                <span class="slash">/</span>
                <span class="month">mo</span>
              </div>
              <ul>
                <li>20GB<span>SSD Disk</span></li>
                <li>512MB<span>Memory</span></li>
                <li>1 Core<span>vCPU</span></li>

                <li>333GB/mo<span>Transfer</span></li>
              </ul>
              <a class="button sign-up" href="https://orders.gigenetcloud.com/order.php?quick=79,20,512,730">Sign Up</a>
            </div>
            <div class="plan">
              <div class="price">
                <span class="dollar">$</span>
                <span class="amount" data-dollar-amount="35.49">35.49</span>
                <span class="slash">/</span>
                <span class="month">mo</span>
              </div>
              <ul>
                <li>30GB<span>SSD Disk</span></li>
                <li>1GB<span>Memory</span></li>
                <li>1 Core<span>vCPU</span></li>
                <li>667GB/mo<span>Transfer</span></li>
              </ul>
              <a class="button sign-up" href="https://orders.gigenetcloud.com/order.php?quick=79,30,1024,730">Sign Up</a>
            </div>
            <div class="plan popular">
              <div class="price">
                <span class="dollar">$</span>
                <span class="amount" data-dollar-amount="56.88">56.88</span>
                <span class="slash">/</span>
                <span class="month">mo</span>
              </div>
                <p class="pop-plan">Most Popular Plan</p>
              <ul>
                <li>40GB<span>SSD Disk</span></li>
                <li>2GB<span>Memory</span></li>
                <li>1 Core<span>vCPU</span></li>
                <li>1333GB/mo<span>Transfer</span></li>
              </ul>
              <a class="button sign-up" href="https://orders.gigenetcloud.com/order.php?quick=79,40,2048,730">Sign Up</a>
            </div>
            <div class="plan">
              <div class="price">
                <span class="dollar">$</span>
                <span class="amount" data-dollar-amount="102.05">102.05</span>
                <span class="slash">/</span>
                <span class="month">mo</span>
              </div>
              <ul>
                <li>60GB<span>SSD Disk</span></li>
                <li>4GB<span>Memory</span></li>
                <li>2 Cores<span>vCPU</span></li>
                <li>2667GB/mo<span>Transfer</span></li>
              </ul>
              <a class="button sign-up" href="https://orders.gigenetcloud.com/order.php?quick=79,60,4096,730">Sign Up</a>
            </div>
            <div class="plan">
              <div class="price">
                <span class="dollar">$</span>
                <span class="amount" data-dollar-amount="202.81">202.81</span>
                <span class="slash">/</span>
                <span class="month">mo</span>
              </div>
              <ul>
                <li>80GB<span>SSD Disk</span></li>
                <li>8GB<span>Memory</span></li>
                <li>4 Cores<span>vCPU</span></li>
                <li>5333GB/mo<span>Transfer</span></li>
              </ul>
              <a class="button sign-up" href="https://orders.gigenetcloud.com/order.php?quick=79,80,8192,730">Sign Up</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div id="hourly" class="wrapper-full hide">
    <p class="bandwidth">Pricing in USD. Excludes any applicable tax.</p>
    <div id="pricing-chart-wrap">
      <div id="pricing-chart">
        <div id="smaller-plans">
            <div class="plan ">
              <div class="price">
                <span class="dollar">$</span>
                <span class="amount" data-dollar-amount="0.03">0.03</span>
                <span class="slash">/</span>
                <span class="month">hr</span>
              </div>
              <ul>
                <li>20GB<span>SSD Disk</span></li>
                <li>512MB<span>Memory</span></li>
                <li>1 Core<span>vCPU</span></li>
                <li>Transfer<span>Pay as you use it</span></li>
              </ul>
              <a class="button sign-up" href="https://orders.gigenetcloud.com/order.php?quick=79,20,512,1">Sign Up</a>
            </div>
            <div class="plan ">
              <div class="price">
                <span class="dollar">$</span>
                <span class="amount" data-dollar-amount="0.05">0.05</span>
                <span class="slash">/</span>
                <span class="month">hr</span>
              </div>
              <ul>
                <li>30GB<span>SSD Disk</span></li>
                <li>1GB<span>Memory</span></li>
                <li>1 Core<span>vCPU</span></li>
                <li>Transfer<span>Pay as you use it</span></li>
              </ul>
              <a class="button sign-up" href="https://orders.gigenetcloud.com/order.php?quick=79,30,1024,1">Sign Up</a>
            </div>
            <div class="plan popular">
              <div class="price">
                <span class="dollar">$</span>
                <span class="amount" data-dollar-amount="0.08">0.08</span>
                <span class="slash">/</span>
                <span class="month">hr</span>
              </div>
              <p class="pop-plan">Most Popular Plan</p>
              <ul>
                <li>40GB<span>SSD Disk</span></li>
                <li>2GB<span>Memory</span></li>
                <li>1 Core<span>vCPU</span></li>
                <li>Transfer<span>Pay as you use it</span></li>
              </ul>
              <a class="button sign-up" href="https://orders.gigenetcloud.com/order.php?quick=79,40,2048,1">Sign Up</a>
            </div>
            <div class="plan">
              <div class="price">
                <span class="dollar">$</span>
                <span class="amount" data-dollar-amount="0.14">0.14</span>
                <span class="slash">/</span>
                <span class="month">hr</span>
              </div>
              <ul>
                <li>60GB<span>SSD Disk</span></li>
                <li>4GB<span>Memory</span></li>
                <li>2 Cores<span>vCPU</span></li>
                <li>Transfer<span>Pay as you use it</span></li>
              </ul>
              <a class="button sign-up" href="https://orders.gigenetcloud.com/order.php?quick=79,60,4096,1">Sign Up</a>
            </div>
            <div class="plan">
              <div class="price">
                <span class="dollar">$</span>
                <span class="amount" data-dollar-amount="0.28">0.28</span>
                <span class="slash">/</span>
                <span class="month">hr</span>
              </div>
              <ul>
                <li>80GB<span>SSD Disk</span></li>
                <li>8GB<span>Memory</span></li>
                <li>4 Cores<span>vCPU</span></li>
                <li>Transfer<span>Pay as you use it</span></li>
              </ul>
              <a class="button sign-up" href="https://orders.gigenetcloud.com/order.php?quick=79,80,8192,1">Sign Up</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: "proxima-nova", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.toggle, .toggler {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 10px;
}

.toggler {
  color: #ddd;
  transition: .2s;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.toggler--is-active {
  color: #9D1726;
}

.b {
  display: block;
}

.toggle {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: #9D1726;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.check {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 6;
}

.check:checked ~ .switch {
  right: 2px;
  left: 57.5%;
  transition: 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
  transition-property: left, right;
  transition-delay: .08s, 0s;
}

.switch {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 57.5%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 36px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
  transition-property: left, right;
  transition-delay: 0s, .08s;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.pricing-section {
    padding: 110px 0 150px 0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.pricing-columns .wrapper-full {
    position: relative;
    width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.pricing-columns #pricing-chart, .pricing-columns-both #pricing-chart {
    margin-top: 100px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.pricing-columns #pricing-chart #smaller-plans, .pricing-columns-both #pricing-chart #smaller-plans {
    display: block;
}
.pricing-columns #pricing-chart .plan, .pricing-columns-both #pricing-chart .plan {
    float: left;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    position: relative;
    color: #454545;
    padding: 14px;
    border-right: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    width: 207px;
}
.pricing-columns #pricing-chart .plan:first-child, .pricing-columns-both #pricing-chart .plan:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}
.pricing-columns #pricing-chart .plan:before, 
.pricing-columns-both #pricing-chart .plan:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 5px;
    left: -1px;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #233E48;
    width: 207px;
}
.pricing-columns #pricing-chart .plan .price, .pricing-columns-both #pricing-chart .plan .price {
    font-size: 26px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    margin-top: 17px;
}
.pricing-columns #pricing-chart .plan .price .dollar, .pricing-columns-both #pricing-chart .plan .price .dollar {
    top: -10px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    left: 3px;
}
.pricing-columns #pricing-chart .plan .price .amount, .pricing-columns-both #pricing-chart .plan .price .amount {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.pricing-columns #pricing-chart .plan .price .slash, .pricing-columns-both #pricing-chart .plan .price .slash {
    font-weight: 600;
    left: -2px;
}
.pricing-columns #pricing-chart .plan .price .month, .pricing-columns-both #pricing-chart .plan .price .month {
    font-weight: 600;
    left: -7px;
}
.pricing-columns #pricing-chart .plan ul, .pricing-columns-both #pricing-chart .plan ul {
    padding: 0 18px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.pricing-columns #pricing-chart .plan ul li, .pricing-columns-both #pricing-chart .plan ul li {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.pricing-columns #pricing-chart .plan ul li span, .pricing-columns-both #pricing-chart .plan ul li span {
    color: #9e9e9e;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 7px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.pricing-columns #pricing-chart .plan a.sign-up, .pricing-columns-both #pricing-chart .plan a.sign-up {
  width: 100%;
    padding: 13px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #9e9e9e;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    clear: left;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.pricing-section .sign-up {
    padding: 17px 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #93cc76;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 600;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: pre;
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.pricing-columns #pricing-chart .popular, .pricing-columns-both #pricing-chart .popular {
    width: 274px;
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: -2px;
    right: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    border-right: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}
.pricing-columns #pricing-chart .popular:before, .pricing-columns-both #pricing-chart .popular:before {
    width: 274px;
    background-color: #9D1726;
    height: 7px;
}
.pricing-columns #pricing-chart .popular a.sign-up, .pricing-columns-both #pricing-chart .popular a.sign-up {
    background-color: #9D1726;
    border: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.pricing-columns #pricing-chart .popular .price .amount, .pricing-columns-both #pricing-chart .popular .price .amount {
    font-size: 60px;
}
.bandwidth {
    display: block;
    color: #9e9e9e;
    font-size: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -90px;
}
.pricing-columns #pricing-chart .popular p.pop-plan, .pricing-columns-both #pricing-chart .popular p.pop-plan {
    color: #454545;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}
.pricing-columns #pricing-chart .popular .price, .pricing-columns-both #pricing-chart .popular .price {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.pricing-columns #pricing-chart .plan a.sign-up:hover, .pricing-columns-both #pricing-chart .plan a.sign-up:hover {
    border: 0;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
var e = document.getElementById("filt-monthly"),
    d = document.getElementById("filt-hourly"),
    t = document.getElementById("switcher"),
    m = document.getElementById("monthly"),
    y = document.getElementById("hourly");

e.addEventListener("click", function(){
  t.checked = false;
  e.classList.add("toggler--is-active");
  d.classList.remove("toggler--is-active");
  m.classList.remove("hide");
  y.classList.add("hide");
});

d.addEventListener("click", function(){
  t.checked = true;
  d.classList.add("toggler--is-active");
  e.classList.remove("toggler--is-active");
  m.classList.add("hide");
  y.classList.remove("hide");
});

t.addEventListener("click", function(){
  d.classList.toggle("toggler--is-active");
  e.classList.toggle("toggler--is-active");
  m.classList.toggle("hide");
  y.classList.toggle("hide");
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have 2 extra closing `</div>` tags in your html (one at line 95 and one at line 182).  This is causing the `#hourly` div to render outside of `.pricing-columns` which results in `#hourly` not picking up the `.pricing-columns` styles.

Remove these extra `</div>` tags and this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have not imported the css file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your quick responses. Crogers' answer of removing those extra div tags solved the problem

Answer (score -1):

I have checked your website. According to that you are not using proper CSS classes for hourly plans. You should add `pricing-columns` class to `#hourly` div. It will work. Rest you can adjust the extra spacing by editing CSS. If you need help with that, let me now.

Comment: You can see this working in [this screenshot](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/4656523/0bfd35dcc8f885ba68140cb54a27fe07). I just added the `pricing-columns` class to desired place.

Comment: While that might technically work, I don't think it is the correct solution.  I believe this is happening because of an extra closing div tag at line 95, which could cause problems later on if it isnt deleted.  The OP should delete the extra tag, along with the extra tag at line 182, and then the .pricing-columns style will cascade to the #hourly div, I believe.

Comment: You could have shared the code for that to be noticed, it can't be noticed from browser. But the issue if of `pricing-columns` class for sure. By deleting the extra div tag you might achieve the proper class before #hourly div. That's why it worked.

You have other problems in your code. No same div should have same ID. But there are exists. Happy that your issue is resolved.